# JavaScript Prototype browser output

Tags: javascript

This is a code the works fine in Codecademy which is where it's from. However, when I try the same code in the browser, it keeps returning undefined.

```
<script>
    function Cat(name, breed) {
      this.name = name;
      this.breed = breed;
    }

    Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
      console.log('Meow!');
    };

    var cheshire = new Cat("Cheshire Cat", "British Shorthair");
    var gary = new Cat("Gary", "Domestic Shorthair");

    alert(console.log(cheshire.meow));
    alert(console.log(gary.meow));
</script>
```

Comment: console.log returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the result of `console.log()` to `alert` but it doesn't return anything so you're passing `undefined` to `alert`.

Either use only `alert` or only `console` log, don't pass one to the other.

Your `meow` function already logs to the console, so doing it again is pointless. Most likely what you want is this:

```
cheshire.meow();
gary.meow();
```

Note that since `meow` is a function, you probably want to actually call it and not just print the function itself.

Comment: So just use `alert(gary.meow);` right? I've already tried that but it returns the actual function instead.

Comment: Or `console.log()`, whichever you'd prefer. I'd probably not use alert because it's annoying to close the windows.

Comment: Mmm, so both `console.log(gary.meow());` and `alert(gary.meow());` return undefined. Just to be sure, there's nothing wrong with the main code?

Comment: @James I missed the obvious issue you're seeing now. Your `meow` function doesn't return anything either. It already logs 'Meow!' to the console using `console.log()`, so your whole issue is sort of redundant anyway. If you made `meow` return a string 'Meow!' then it would work as you expect. `meow = function(){return 'Meow!'}`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Got you! I understand that my previous code was just logging to the console. So besides for debugging/checking your code, I assume you should always use `return`?

Comment: @James That's really more a question of if your function needs to return anything. If your function accepted inputs and added them, then you'd want to return the sum. If your function had conditional outcomes, like an async request, you might want to return `true` or `false` depending on whether it succeeded or not.